# What credentials to add to win10 shared folder to let win98 machine in?

Tags: network-shares, smb

We moved to another location and got a completely different server installed and I've had some issues with the older machines with WinXP and Win98 (these are rack mounted PCs and upgrading the machines is out of the question, since they only run their own softare and thats it).

Issues lie with the network shares and I've decided not to go the route of lowering all security down to the acceptable level (signing off, turn SMBv1 on etc), but rather use another non-critical buffer computer to serve the working files to older machines.

I've already attached few XP machines to the new buffer computer, but I'm having trouble figuring out the Win98 machine, mostly because the NET USER command doesn't allow the NTFS user name to be defined.

On the buffer Win10 machine I've turned the accepted signing to the lower (56/40 bit?) signing, turned SMBv1 back on and I've installed the dsclient addition to the win98 machine that lets it use the NTLM2 protocol. I've also given full rights to the (NT AUTHORITY/) "Anonymous Logon" / "Everyone" user to the win10 machine on the share I want to add, but the win98 machine just rejects the login and keeps asking for the password.

In the event viewer I can see that there is a attempt to access from
SID: empty
USER: the name of the logged in user in the win98
DOMAIN: the workgroup the win98 machine is in (alone)

How should I modify the settings on the Win10 machine to let this user in?

I guess also matching the same username and domain on the win98 machine with valid user on the win10 share also works?

Comment: This is probably not possible because Windows 98 is just too old.  Collect what data you need on a USB drive and get the data that way.

Comment: Simple FTP server on the "buffer" machine?  Win98 explorer worked seamlessly with FTP (a feature I believe they removed).

Comment: The computer on the rack of the machine is 166MHz pentium with nothing more than LPT port and few COM ports hardwired to the machine control cards. There is no USB to use.

FTP'ing files over one at a time is not really an option for the operator either, since it opens risk of having different versions of files at the machine.

Floppy drive is also busted, so thats not an option at the moment either :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't spend time on that at all. Set up Samba on Debian 10 as a file server – it cooperates well even with Windows versions requiring legacy LANMAN support (enable `lanman auth=` and `ntlm auth=` before creating the Samba user accounts), and it will be a bit more secure as a "buffer" machine than Windows 10. (It also doesn't require Client Access Licenses, doesn't automatically reboot for updates at inopportune times, and can run on whatever XP-era potato PC you have around.)

Note: Debian 10 is deliberate, as it comes with Samba 4.9 – I *think* the version of Samba that comes with Debian 11 no longer has legacy LANMAN support?

(Though, yes, old Samba could have had security issues as well... I have a host that runs a modern distribution with SMBv3 and Kerberos on the "outside", but shares its /data directory with a container that provides SMBv1/LANMAN to the "inside".)

You might also consider using SSH/SFTP file transfer instead; WinSCP 4.4.0 and PuTTY 0.63 work on Windows 98 and can connect to modern OpenSSH. (You do need to re-enable slightly weaker ciphers, but that's a *very* minor problem realistically.)

> mostly because the NET USER command doesn't allow the NTFS user name to be defined.

If I remember correctly, Windows 98 did not support specifying the username per-connection – it always used the username that you logged in as (through the "Primary Network Logon" component). There is a separate `net logon` command.

> I've also given full rights to the (NT AUTHORITY/) "Anonymous Logon" / "Everyone" user to the win10 machine on the share I want to add, but the win98 machine just rejects the login and keeps asking for the password.

Rights on the share have nothing to do with passwords – they are only checked *after* you have successfully authenticated to the server as a whole. Windows NT doesn't do share-level authentication anymore; it is entirely system-account-based.